# Modifying the number of layers of a matrix variable

Tags: r, variables

I am currently trying to modify the number of a variable's layers. The variable is called "Model4" and is a matrix. It currently has 95 layers. However, I would like to create a new Model4 (let's say "NewModel4"), in which it has 90 layers, instead of 95 layers. Therefore, the idea would be to make Model4's layer number 90 by only using those first 90 layers.

I have already attempted the following:

```
new.data<-dplyr::between(Model4,0,89)
```

Yields this error:

```
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=S4; target=double].
```

I then tried this:

```
newfile<-Model4[Model4$onedaymax %in% (0:89),]
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : invalid layer names
```

I then tried this:

```
NewModel4 <- Model4[0:89,]
```

While this went through, the length of NewModel4 was 8550!

From dput(Model4):

```
file = new(".RasterFile"
, datanotation = "FLT4S"
, byteorder = "little"
, nodatavalue = -Inf
, NAchanged = FALSE
, nbands = 95L
, bandorder = "BIL"
, offset = 0L
, toptobottom = TRUE
, blockrows = 0L
, blockcols = 0L
, driver = "netcdf"
, open = FALSE
)
, data = new(".MultipleRasterData"
, values = structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(0L, 0L))
, offset = 0
, gain = 1
, inmemory = FALSE
, fromdisk = TRUE
, nlayers = 95L
, dropped = NULL
, isfactor = FALSE
, attributes = list()
, haveminmax = FALSE
, min = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf)
, max = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf)
, unit = "mm/day"
, names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", 
"X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", 
"X20", "X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", "X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", 
"X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", "X33", "X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", 
"X38", "X39", "X40", "X41", "X42", "X43", "X44", "X45", "X46", 
"X47", "X48", "X49", "X50", "X51", "X52", "X53", "X54", "X55", 
"X56", "X57", "X58", "X59", "X60", "X61", "X62", "X63", "X64", 
"X65", "X66", "X67", "X68", "X69", "X70", "X71", "X72", "X73", 
"X74", "X75", "X76", "X77", "X78", "X79", "X80", "X81", "X82", 
"X83", "X84", "X85", "X86", "X87", "X88", "X89", "X90", "X91", 
"X92", "X93", "X94", "X95")
)
, legend = new(".RasterLegend"
, type = character(0)
, values = logical(0)
, color = logical(0)
, names = logical(0)
, colortable = logical(0)
)
, title = "onedaymax"
, extent = new("Extent"
, xmin = -181.40625
, xmax = 178.59375
, ymin = -89.258464857103
, ymax = 89.258464857103
)
, rotated = FALSE
, rotation = new(".Rotation"
, geotrans = numeric(0)
, transfun = function () 
NULL
)
, ncols = 128L
, nrows = 64L
, crs = new("CRS"
, projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
)
, history = list()
, z = list(1:95)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share your data with `dput(Model4)`. Also I don't think `between` is designed for that although there could be a way to use it to "subset".

Comment: Hi NelsonGon, Thank you for your response. I just added the data that you requested in my original post. Also, the "length" of Model4 is not 95, but rather that there are 95 "layers". The actual length of Model4 is 778240 (presumably taking into account all 95 layers).

Comment: @NelsonGon Just to build on my post above this one, I think the 778240 from "length(Model4)" refers to the number of cells over the 95 layers. In any case, the goal would still be to bring this down to 90 layers by considering only the first 90.